# CSS h1-h3 color in .class

Tags: css, css-selectors

My code is

```
   .simple-text h2 {color:red;}
   .simple-text h3 {color:red;}
   .simple-text h4 {color:red;}

<div class="simple-text">
 <h1>Header 1</h1>
 <h2>Header 2</h2>
 <h3>Header 3</h3>
</div>
```

How to write short css?

```
      .simple-text h1,h2,h3 {color:red;}
```

Don't work

I need all Headers in DIV with class "simple-text" were red

Comment: I don't think you can make it that much neater, unless you use something like Sass or Less to allow e.g. `.simple-text { h1, h2, h3 { color: red; } }`

Comment: Side note, your CSS targets h2, h3, and h4 but your code example has h1, h2, and h3

Answer (score 2):

With plain CSS you're limited to:

```css
.simple-text h1,
.simple-text h2,
.simple-text h3 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="simple-text">
  <h1>Header 1</h1>
  <h2>Header 2</h2>
  <h3>Header 3</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you tried this ?

```
.simple-text h1,.simple-text h2,.simple-text h3 {color:red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there's no "short" way to do this in plain CSS.  I would suggest you check out LESS though.  It's a CSS Preprocessor that adds just this kind of thing. In LESS you can do the following:

```
.simple-text
{
  h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6
  {
    color:red;
  }
}
```

There's also lots more in LESS.  There are other preprocessors like SASS, too.  I recommend doing your homework, they can save you lots of time.

Comment: Or SASS, SCSS!!

Comment: Just posting the one I'm sure about the syntax on.  I'm planning to migrate once Bootstrap 4 comes out but until then.

Comment: on css there is no solution, I need to use less, thank you for your answers

Comment: Please mark an answer (even if it's not mine). Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

move the headers within the .simple-text css class

```
.simple-text {
  h1, h2, h3 {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

EDIT: I misread the question. This is SASS.

Comment: That's not valid CSS. Maybe it's valid using a pre-processor like sass or less, which the question isn't tagged with, but not plain CSS.